# Chart Js - Wasting Graph Space

Tags: javascript, graph, charts

Does anyone know why Chart JS wastes Graph Space? Why does it not take up the full width of the graph?

The graph is sitting in a bootstrap container > row if that makes a difference?

[image: Chart JS Wasting Space]

This is My Code:

```
<canvas id="mostPopularProductionApps" width="100" height="150"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
barChartCreator(prodChart, prodLabels, prodData, '# Heorku AddOns', 'Number of AddOns Per Applications');  

barChartCreator: function(DOMLocation, labels, data, label, title) {
      var createdChart = new Chart(DOMLocation, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
              labels: labels,
              datasets: [{
                  label: label,
                  data: data,
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                  borderWidth: 1
              }]
          },
          options: {
              scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero: true
                      }
                  }]
              },
              title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: title
              }
          }
      });
      return createdChart;
    },
```

Comment: Share your code so that somebody may help

Comment: You are breaking your code